# How do I get the screen DPI using wxPython?

Tags: wxpython, dpi

I can get the screen resolution in with

```
wx.DisplaySize()
```

but I don't see a method which gives me the DPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any such function in wxPython, what you can do instead is, by using ctypes call win32api function [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(VS.85).aspx) and get LOGPIXELSX/LOGPIXELSY

Comment: `ctypes` is still uncharted waters for me, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution may be:

```
import wx
app = wx.App(0)
print wx.ScreenDC().GetPPI()
```

I tested it on Windows XP and it indeed prints (96, 96) with the default DPI-setting and (120, 120) with 120 DPI-setting.

Comment: This prints 96 on a monitor that definitely is higher than 96. Qt works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271887/calculate-screen-dpi