# Calculate screen DPI

Tags: python, windows, dpi

I am using Python to build an image-rendering app that renders numpy arrays as images. I need a way to automate the calculation screen DPI, as I am generating images of the same size on different monitors (e.g., 2x2 inches). I am in Windows 10, Python 3.7.

I am *not* asking how to get the monitor's *screen size* -- like finding out if your monitor is 3000x2000 pixels (as was solved at: [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python/31171430#31171430)).

Rather, I want something that calculates DPI speficially, and takes into account any scale settings the user has applied that might change the DPI of their system. E.g., I have the scale set to 250%.

Following this answer at experts-exchange (https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21794611/Detecting-system-DPI-settings-in-Python.html), I have tried using this:

```
from ctypes import windll

def get_ppi():
    LOGPIXELSX = 88
    LOGPIXELSY = 90
    user32 = windll.user32
    user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
    dc = user32.GetDC(0)   
    pix_per_inch = windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSX)
    print("Horizontal DPI is", windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSX))
    print("Vertical DPI is", windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSY))
    user32.ReleaseDC(0, dc)
    return pix_per_inch
```

It seems to be the right ballpark, but returns a number that is too low. It returns 240, while my actual DPI is closer to 285.

I would prefer to avoid using a GUI framework like Qt for this, as I want to minimize overhead, but if that's the only way, then I will! If I do have to use a framework, I'd prefer PyQt5.

Comment: Perhaps you have DPI per monitor set? In that case, try `GetDpiForWindow()` with `winDpi = user32.GetDpiForWindow(window)`

Comment: @mnistic that sounds cool, but it seems to not work for me: when I try it for `window=0` in my code, I just get back 0. Unless I'm setting it wrong?

Comment: Pass actual window handle to `GetDpiForWindow()`, use `GetDpiForSystem()` to get the system DPI, i.e. `sysDpi = user32.GetDpiForSystem()`

Comment: @mnistic this sounds like it would make for a great answer :) The GetDpiForSystem returns 240 which is what my initial try returns. Obviously I'm not very good with all this `windll.user32` stuff :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I said I wanted to avoid it, there is one very simple way to pull this off using PyQt5. The more I think about it, the more I think this could be the best solution, as it is largely platform independent:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = app.screens()[0]
dpi = screen.physicalDotsPerInch()
app.quit()
```

Note that `app.screens()` returns a list of screens. In my case I only have one attached but you may have multiple, so be sure to be aware of which screen you need to get dpi from. And if you keep all this contained in a function, it won't clutter your namespace with PyQt junk.

Also, for more on QScreen (`sc` is a QScreen object) see this doc page:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html

There's all sorts of cool stuff you can pull from it.

Comment: probably the better DPI grab method from QScreen is logicalDotsPerIngh().  I found that when I was using "physical", I would get numbers like 94.56 when the spec is 96.  "logical" actually returns the 96, which if you are looking to do your own physical scaling, is a better number to use.

Answer (score 9):

While [@eric's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54273855/7496549) answer works, I would prefer to avoid leaving the standard library (ignoring the distributions of Python that don't include `ctypes`).

This initially led me to ctypes and you can see my initial (very over-complicated) answer which can be found below. More recently I found a way to do it with just Tk (I can't remember the link to it so will link to a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469642) which has the same content)

```py
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
dpi = root.winfo_fpixels('1i')
```

**Original answer**

The following answer offers two solutions:

1. The first is Windows' reported DPI due to the user's display scaling
2. The second is the monitor's true DPI calculated by finding the monitor's physical size and resolution

These solutions assume there is only one monitor and also sets process DPI awareness (which won't be suitable for some contexts). For details on the Windows API calls made by `ctypes` see the documentation for [`SetProcessDPIAwareness`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness), [`GetDPIForWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforwindow), [`GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) and [`GetDeviceCaps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps).

**Solution 1**

This solution doesn't return a proper DPI, and is instead just Window's "zoom factor" for that monitor. To get the factor, you should divide the returned DPI by  `96` (meaning `96` is a scale factor of `100%` while `120` means a scale factor of `125%`, etc.).

The method uses `tkinter` to get a valid `HWND` (an identifier for the window) and then `ctypes` to get the DPI for the new window.

```py
# Import the libraries
import ctypes
import tkinter

# Set process DPI awareness
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
# Create a tkinter window
root = tkinter.Tk()
# Get the reported DPI from the window's HWND
dpi = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDpiForWindow(root.winfo_id())
# Print the DPI
print(dpi)
# Destroy the window
root.destroy()
```

**Solution 2**

This method should return the monitor's true DPI, however, two things should be noted:

1. The physical size of the monitor is (occasionally) reported incorrectly. This will therefore result in a completely incorrect DPI value, though I am not sure how to prevent this except add a check to ensure it is between sensible values (whatever that means!).
2. The resolution Windows is using is often different to the monitor's actual resolution. This method calculates the monitor's true DPI, but if you want to calculate the number of virtual pixels per physical inch, you would replace the assignment of `dw` and `dh` with `root.winfo_screenwidth()` and `root.winfo_screenheight()` (respectively)

This method uses `tkinter` to get a valid `HWND` (an identifier for the window) and then `ctypes` to get a Device Context (DC) & hardware details from this.

```py
# Our convertion from millimeters to inches
MM_TO_IN = 0.0393700787

# Import the libraries
import ctypes
import math
import tkinter

# Set process DPI awareness
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
# Create a tkinter window
root = tkinter.Tk()
# Get a DC from the window's HWND
dc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(root.winfo_id())
# The the monitor phyical width
# (returned in millimeters then converted to inches)
mw = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, 4) * MM_TO_IN
# The the monitor phyical height
mh = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, 6) * MM_TO_IN
# Get the monitor horizontal resolution
dw = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, 8)
# Get the monitor vertical resolution
dh = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(dc, 10)
# Destroy the window
root.destroy()

# Horizontal and vertical DPIs calculated
hdpi, vdpi = dw / mw, dh / mh
# Diagonal DPI calculated using Pythagoras
ddpi = math.hypot(dw, dh) / math.hypot(mw, mh)
# Print the DPIs
print(round(hdpi, 1), round(vdpi, 1), round(ddpi, 1))
```

Comment: I only have one monitor and am on Windows10, but your two different solutions give two very different answers, neither which is the `100` I was expecting. The first solution gives `96`, the second solution gives `141.8 141.4 141.7`

Comment: The first solution doesn't return a proper DPI, and is instead just Window's "zoom factor" for that monitor (`96` means that you have set it to `100%` - `125%` would report as `120` DPI). The second answer should only be giving an incorrect reading if the physical dimensions are incorrectly reported or the `100` you stated is calculated using the resolution you are driving rather than your monitor's true resolution (you can check the numbers to help debug).

Comment: Note: If you did want to the number of virtual pixels per physical inch, you would replace the assignment of `dw` and `dh` with `root.winfo_screenwidth()` and `root.winfo_screenheight()` (respectively)

Comment: This is why I just use Qt. Things get complicated when I don't. They are simple/Pythonic when I do. :)

Comment: @ProQ I don't know if there is any relation here of if it's a coincidence, but `100 x sqrt(2) == 141.4`.

Comment: I ended up with an additional window when I did this with the "root" window, so I ended up using `plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.winfo_fpixels('1i')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Qt, you can use your last approach because in my case, there is a 45.95 dpi difference between a Qt solution and ctypes solution. I think it's always the same for all laptops. Just add (45.96 dpi) on your result every time you use ctypes.

[image: screen shot for representation]

Comment: Very interesting I haven't checked this but if it works that would be really nice!